# jquery/ajax call to webapi and URL encoding with backslash

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, routes, urlencode

For purely debugging/testing/hack reasons, I have an html page that takes in a username - e.g. MyDomain\JohnDoe and authenticates the user.

My question is, how do I send/encode and setup the webapi routes/decode the full username with the backslash \? I tried encodeURIComponent that changse the \ into %5C, but then the webapi routes don't work. If I leave off the \, then the routes work and the action method is hit.

HTML PAGE:
            $('#authenticate').click(function () {

```
            var username = encodeURIComponent($('#username').val());
            var password = encodeURIComponent($('#password').val());
            var uri = 'http://localhost/api/tester/' + username + '/' + password;
            $.ajax({
                url: uri;
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    $('#authenticationMessage').text(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                    $('#authenticationMessage').text('Error: ' + err + ' --   ' + uri);
                }
            });
        });
```

CONTROLLER:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/tester")
public class AuthenticationClientTesterController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{username}/{password}", Name = "GetAuthenticatedTester")]
    public async Task<string> GetAuthenticated(string username, string password)
    {
        string message = "You are NOT authenticated.  " + username;
        return message;
    }
}
```

Suggestions greatly welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You totally should forget about sending special characters in the path portion of an url as Scott Hanselman explains in this blog post: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx

I will only quote his conclusion that should put you on the right track of what you should be doing:

> After ALL this effort to get crazy stuff in the Request Path, it's
>   worth mentioning that simply keeping the values as a part of the Query
>   String (remember WAY back at the beginning of this post?) is easier,
>   cleaner, more flexible, and more secure.

So, `encodeURIComponent` is great for sending values as query string parameters or POST values which is how usernames and passwords should be sent.